# помощь в разборке Gson и создание обьекта

Tags: java, массивы, json, gson

У меня есть ответ с сервера в виде json. Так же имеется обработка.

Проблема в том что я не могу создать обьект `data` с данными  из строки полученной с помощью `gson`.

```
    public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String url = "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films";
            URL obj = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
//                response.append("\n");
            }

            in.close();

//            System.out.println(response.toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", ""));
            String resString = response.toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", "");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String gsonString = gson.toJson(resString);
            System.out.println(gsonString);
            Data data = gson.fromJson(resString, Data.class);
            
            System.out.println(data);
//
//            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("title");
//            System.out.println(name);
//            Ghibli ghibli = new Ghibli();
//            ghibli.startApp();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ghibli.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

//     ghibli.getData("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films");
    }

}
```

Класс с данными у меня выглядит просто, поля и конструктор:

```
class Data {

private String id;
private String title;
@SerializedName("original_title")
private String mOriginal_title;
@SerializedName("original_title_romanised")
private String mOriginal_title_romanised;
private String description;
private String director;
private String producer;
@SerializedName("release_date")
private int mRelease_date;
@SerializedName("running_time")
private int mRunning_time;
@SerializedName("rt_score")
private int mRt_score;
private String[] people;
private String[] species;
private String[] locations;
private String[] vehicles;
private String[] url;

public Data(String id, String title, String mOriginal_title, String mOriginal_title_romanised, String description, String director, String producer, int mRelease_date, int mRunning_time, int mRt_score, String[] people, String[] species, String[] locations, String[] vehicles, String[] url) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.mOriginal_title = mOriginal_title;
    this.mOriginal_title_romanised = mOriginal_title_romanised;
    this.description = description;
    this.director = director;
    this.producer = producer;
    this.mRelease_date = mRelease_date;
    this.mRunning_time = mRunning_time;
    this.mRt_score = mRt_score;
    this.people = people;
    this.species = species;
    this.locations = locations;
    this.vehicles = vehicles;
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

куда идет запрос ( это прямо по ссылке "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films" ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

какой ответ приходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть сомнения по поводу resString и gsonString по сути это одни и теже строчки. Но что из той ничего не получаеться создать что и из другой

Comment: Очень подозрительно выгляит вот это: `.replaceAll("^.|.$", "");` - что и зачем вы меняете в ответе сервера? У вас там, наверное, какой-то JSON - его не надо, по идее, никак модифицировать, это может всё сломать. И напишите подробнее что у вас не так - какие-то ошибки?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сама ошибка выглядит таким образом: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $/\.  .replaceAll("^.|.$", "") - я использую для того что бы убрать скобки, что бы получить чистый json. Есть конечно возможность что я ошибаюсь

Comment: Попробуйте убрать вашу регулярку - 99% что она вам не нужна, т.к. с вероятностью 99,(9)% у вас и так с сервера валидный JSON возвращается.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб результат такой же: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $.... Я скорее всего неверно представляю данные во что должна превратиться данная строка json.

Comment: Покажите что вам с сервера приходит - может там что-то неожиданное.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил правками к вопросу...

Comment: У вас не одна Data, но массив оных. Т.е. парсить надо как-то так: `List<Data> datas = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Data>>(){}.getType());  `

Comment: @ЮрийСПб все равно не хочет нормально парситься: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 711 path $[0].people[0].    `@SerializedName("people")
private List<People> mPeople;` верно ли что я задаю list?

Comment: Вроде правильно. Попробуйте удалять из класса переменные чтобы понять какая из них ломает парсинг

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да все верно. у меня просто уже отличался, класс data от того что в вопросе  проблема была в list,  надо было простой массив создавать. Ставьте ваше решение в ответ помечу его  как "ответ".

Comment: Вы можете сами написать ответ) Я на даче с телефона не смогу набрать ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Хорошо ).  у меня тогда еще один глупый вопрос. по доступам к полям этого созданного объекта. по всем объектам я например прошелся циклом, а как получить доступ именно к значению этого обьекта который находиться на какой то i-ой интерации?

Comment: Вопрос не очень понял( возможно вы что то такое имеете в виду? datas.get(10).title?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, типо того я уже просто через гетер получаю доступ. data.getDescription(). Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в неправильном представлении мною данных. Так как с сервера приходит не одна конкретная `data` а множество, то надо исправить мой парсер на

`List<Data> datas = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Data>>(){}.getType());`.

Что позволяет создавать множество data, а не одну.